# Bubble sort em matriz, vetor bi dimensional

Tags: c, classificação

Não estou conseguindo criar um *bubble sort* que ordene uma matriz quadrada.
Vetor simples eu consigo, o problema eh com matriz. Testei de diversas formas e nada.

No momento estou na seguinte configuração:

```
void ordem(int *matriz [][n])
{
    int temp, l, c;
    for(l=0; l<n; l++){
      for(c=0; c<=n-l; c++){
        if(matriz[l][c] > matriz[l][c+1]){
          temp = matriz[l][c];
          matriz[l][c] = matriz[l][c+1];
          matriz[l][c+1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Se precisar posto o código inteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, lendo o seu código o problema dele é o seguinte...
O primeiro for() faz as interações passando de linha em linha da sua matriz.
O segundo for() faz as interações percorrendo as colunas da matriz. Ao encontrar um valor na posição c que seja maior do que c+1, ambos na mesma linha, você traca os valores de posição. OK! Mas isso não é o bubble sort. Você precisa criar um terceiro laço continuar verificando se aquele elemento que estava na coluna c ainda é maior do que o em c-1. Por exemplo:

7 8 5 4
0 6 5 4
1 4 2 5
2 4 2 5

Vamos executar seu código apenas na primeira linha:
1- 7 é maior do que 8? não! continua o laço...
2- 8 é maior do que 5? sim! troca! continua o laço...
agora temos na primeira linha o seguinte:

7 5 8 4

3- 8 é maior do que 4? sim! troca! continua o laço...

7 5 4 8

Vê o problema? Ele não continua ordenando...

Minha sugestão é a seguinte:
fica "feio" criar um laço a mais ai... Eu acho. 
Crie um programa que percorra linha a linha da matriz e chame o bubble sort para cada linha. Até porque, cada linha ainda é um vetor, certo? E vetores você sabe organizar. Passe para a função de bubble que você criou para vetores a linha da matriz. Pronto.

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que está a haver alguma confusão de inteiros e apontadores. Na função aparece:

```
(apontador > apontador )    // possivel mas não me parece que queiras isso
int = apontador             // raramente é o pretendido
apontador = apontador       // neste caso não me parece que seja o que queres
```

Portando sugeria rever:

- a declaração da matrix (presentemente tens uma matriz de apontadores para inteiros) --> convinha matriz de intereiros (ex `int matriz[][n]`)
- `cc -Wall` para ajudar a apontar algumas destes situações

Passando a coisas sérias, Ordenar um quadrado pode ter muitas especificações possíveis:
Se eu bem entendi, o teu algoritmo está a ordenar as linhas mas não as linhas entre si.

Qual o resultado pretenddo?

Comment: O pretendido é organizar as linhas e não as colunas

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer, coragem: (completa o enunciado), corrige a declaração, altera e dá-nos a resposta final a que chegaste para nós a votarmos!